# Handling rebase in development branch after PR

Tags: git, github

I'm working on an ongoing project in early stages where we have one development branch per developer. So when some feature is implemented we create a PR (github) and merge it to master. After the PR I want to continue working with my development branch (same one).

**What is the correct way of updating my development branch to match the new master? And how to continue working with my development branch after a PR from the same branch?**

I've tried `git rebase master` standing in my development branch. Then I get the commits again, since they were merged into the master from my branch already (due to the PR). That makes my development branch in front of the origin of my development branch. This results in a merge within my development branch.

Sometimes, if some other commits from other users were included in the master branch and I have rebased and want to create a new PR. Their commits ends up in my PR as well. Commits that they already merged into master. I've tried so many things and I'm pretty confused by now...

So what I thought was correct is the following work flow:

```
<merge PR on github>
git checkout master 
git pull --rebase
git checkout my-dev-branch
git rebase master
<continue working in my-dev-branch>
```

However, something isn't right here since it causes strange merges/inclusion of other users commits etc.

Comment: I actually recommend _not_ continuing to use your development branch, once the feature has been completed.  Why do you want to keep using it?

Comment: Since it's basically a generic dev-branch which could include multiple features or changes. So it's not "featureX", it's rather "stuff-this-week" kinda branches. But would it be better to remove the branch and re-create with the same name?

Later on in the project it makes sense to have feature-branches. But not right now.

Comment: I'm not a Git expert, but I have rarely seen anyway using the workflow you are suggesting.  Rather, once a feature is completed, and the branch merged, that branch is not used anymore for other work.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the easiest way without causing any strange issues.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this rhetorical question: What's the correct screwdriver to use on a nail, flat-head or Phillips?

---

Somewhat more practically: all `git rebase` does is *copy* (some set of) commits, then yank a branch name around.  That is, *before* `git rebase` you might have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- feature
```

You run `git checkout feature; git rebase master` with the goal: *replace existing commits `I-J-K` with a new series of commits, copied from `I`, `J`, and `K`, such that the new and improved commits look like this:*

```
             I'-J'-K'  <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

This is a reasonable thing to do *as long as no one else is using `I-J-K`*.  If no one else *has* them, it's safe to do at any time.  If Bob and Carol have them, but aren't *using* them, and you can convince Bob and Carol to switch to your new replacement commits without disrupting their work at all, it's *still* safe to do, but now you have to coordinate with two other people.

In some cases, it may be reasonable to do even if others are using the original chain and depend on it.  Here, *they* have to know how to deal with *their* commits, because now *they* have their own additional commits in *their* repositories:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- feature
                 \
                  L   <-- bob
```

After you replace `I-J-K` with the new-and-improved `I'-J'-K'`, Bob will have to replace his own `L` with his own new-and-improved `L'`.  That *may* be OK, but it's good to verify this with Bob before you go do it.

#### What about a merged PR?

This is where things get extra-complicated, especially if people are using the "rebase and merge" or "squash and merge" buttons on GitHub.

The rebase-and-merge button on GitHub makes *GitHub* do this same replacement trick.  That is, they take your `I-J-K` chain and *copy* it.  **They do this even if there's no good reason to do it.**  That is, suppose your commits look like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

This series of commits **could** simply be *added on* to the existing commits, by having the name `master` slide down-and-right in what Git calls a *fast-forward* operation:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature, master
```

But GitHub will not do this.  When you (or someone) use the rebase-and-merge button, they will instead do:

```
             I'-J'-K'  <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   [your PR - abandoned]
```

If *you* have an extra commit `L` that comes after `K`, *you* are now in the same position as Bob earlier.  You must copy your `L` to a new `L'` that comes after `K'`, without also copying `I-J-K` yet again.

The easiest thing to do is *not* to have `L` at all.  Just abandon your branch named `feature` (e.g., delete it entirely), bring your `master` up to date so that you have commit `K'`, and then create the name `feature` again, pointing to `K'`:

```
...--F--G--H--I'-J'-K'  <-- feature, master
```

No one (including yourself) will ever remember the hash IDs of the original `I-J-K` chain, and it will "feel like" you're just continuing where you left off when you do eventually make commit `L` that comes after `K'`:

```
...--F--G--H--I'-J'-K'  <-- master
                     \
                      L   <-- feature
```

The "squash and merge" button works much like the "rebase and merge" button, except that instead of copying the chain of commits one commit at a time, GitHub will make one single commit that has the same *effect* as if they had copied the commits:

```
...--F--G--H--IJK   <-- master
```

where commit `IJK` is the result of merging `K` (as if via `git merge`) but then making an ordinary single-parent commit (hence, more as if via `git merge --squash`).  As before, if you already have an `L` that comes off your original `K`, you must abandon your `L` in favor of a new copy `L'` that comes after new commit `IJK`.

#### If you are Bob

You can use `git rebase --onto` to do this sort of thing relatively convenient, once you're in the situation we originally ascribed to Bob, here.  The `--onto` option lets you tell Git: *put the copies after my updated `master`* while also letting you tell Git: *don't copy commit `K` or anything earlier than `K`*.  Without `--onto`, your `git rebase` takes *one* argument which is both *where to put the copies* and *what not to copy*, and you need to separate them.

In some cases, Git can actually figure this sort of thing out for you.  That's what the `--fork-point` mode of `git rebase`, available (and default!) since Git version 2.0, is about.  Unfortunately, none of these cases apply to GitHub and its rebase-and-merge or squash-and-merge buttons.  In other cases, one of which *does* apply here, Git can *still* figure this out—but if you're seeing a lot of problems with a rebase, that means Git *didn't* figure it out, and you probably want `git rebase --onto` if you want `git rebase` at all.

Comment: Sorry to bring your attention back to a year-old answer, but I'd like to know what the answer to your rhetorical question is in the world of git. In DIY world the answer is hammer. From reading your answer I think the git-world answer is 'delete the branch and create a new one'. Is that right?

Comment: @KitJohnson: well, "it depends" :-) ... if you don't have a hammer, you can perhaps use the back of either screwdriver, for instance, though something metal (wrench?) might be better. In Git-land, what you said would generally be the right answer (as would be the hammer for the rhetorical question) but there might be some weird special case that would call for figuring something else out.

Comment: Thank you. This has been a very helpful discussion for me.